# Injecting dll before windows executes target TLS callbacks

Tags: c++, dll-injection

There's an app that uses TLS callbacks to remap its memory using (`NtCreateSection/NtUnmapViewOfSection/NtMapViewOfSection`) using the `SEC_NO_CHANGE` flag.

Is there any way to hook `NtCreateSection` before the target app use it on its TLS callback?

Comment: You could always try doing that from the parent process and trying to hook the PE loader in `ntdll.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor#Download) to check if it is really that function call and if I understand you correctly you want to modify its invocation. API Monitor allows you to modify the parameters on the fly. If just "patching" the value when the application accesses the api is enough you could than use [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/#start) to craft a persistent binary patch for your application. But this requires you to at least know or get familiar with basic x64/x86 assembler.

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve exactly but if you're trying to execute setup code before the *main()* function is called (to setup hooks), you could use the **constructor** on a **static object**. You would basically construct an object before your main program starts.

```
// In a .cpp file (do not put in a header as that would create multiple static objects!)
class StaticIntitializer {
    StaticIntitializer(){
        std::cout << "This will run before your main function...\n";
        /* This is where you would setup all your hooks */
    }
};

static StaticInitializer staticInitializer;
```

Beware though, as any object constructed this way might get constructed in any order depending on compilers, files order, etc. Also, some things might not be initialized yet and you might not be able to achieve what you want to setup.

That might be a good starting point, but as I said, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here, so good luck and I hope it helps a little.